# How to get sum from third relation table

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a expenses tracking system and stuck in some part.

I have 3 tables in database.

Table 1(projects)

[image]

Table 2(category)

[image]

Table 3(expenses)

[image]

tblProjects relate to tblCategory with 1:1, tblExpenses relate to tblProjects also with 1:1.

Now, I'm trying to get the sum of each category. For instance I want to know what is the total amount spent for Trip, Sports etc.

I try to get with below query, but it returns me wrong data

```
SELECT category.cat_title as Category, (select sum(expenses.exp_amount) 
from expenses
where expenses.projects_id = projects.proj_id) as Total_Expenses                
from category inner join projects on projects.proj_cat = category.cat_id 
group by category.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT category.cat_title,sum(expenses.exp_amount) as Category from 
category inner join projects on projects.proj_cat = category.cat_id
inner join expenses where expenses.projects_id = projects.proj_id
group by category.cat_title
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried and its work. but, is there any difference when using WHERE or ON in the INNER JOIN part?

Comment: no in case of inner join there is no difference - btw, if it helped u please mark it as accepted answer :) @HafizK

Comment: you had used scalar subquery and that's why may be your result was wrong @HafizK

Comment: The reason I used subquery is because I have another table(incomes) which i thought can use the same way to get the data. unfortunately its not. your query above is worked for if only get the sum for expenses, but i cannot use the same method to sum another column from another table. Can i still amend my question?

Comment: yes, you can amend your question - but it would be good if you accept this answer as it serves your above answer and creates a separate question with your all details :) @HafizK

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks @fa06